# Python importing a module from a parallel directory

Tags: python, import, module, parent, relative-import

How would I organize my python imports so that I can have a directory like this.

```
project
|      \
|      __init__.py
|     
src
|   \
|    __init__.py
|    classes.py
|
test
    \
     __init__.py
     tests.py
```

And then inside /project/test/tests.py be able to import classes.py

I've got code looking like this in tests.py

```
from .. src.classes import(
    scheduler
    db
)
```

And am getting errors of

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Python adds the folder containing the script you launch to the PYTHONPATH, so if you run

```
python test/tests.py
```

Only the folder `test` is added to the path (not the base dir that you're executing the command in).

Instead run your tests like so:

```
python -m test.tests
```

This will add the base dir to the python path, and then classes will be accessible via a non-relative import:

```
from src.classes import etc
```

If you really want to use the relative import style, then your 3 dirs need to be added to a package directory

```
package
* __init__.py
* project
* src
* test
```

And you execute it from above the package dir with

```
python -m package.test.tests
```

See also:

- https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html
- http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath

Comment: If you get, "No module named test.tests", make sure you have an `__init__.py` in your `test/` directory.