# how to import from parallel directory in pycharm with python 2.7

Tags: python, import, parent

I get a directory like the following:

```
__init__.py
common
|      \
|      __init__.py
|      util.py
|     
sites
    \
     __init__.py
     site_a.py
```

The folder where 'common' and 'sites' locat  is named 'father'
I'd like to import common/util.py from inside sites/site_a.py.
I tried to use: from father.common import util
But pycharm reports: unsolved reference 'father'

How shall I import util.py from inside site_a.py?
PS: I don't want to change my PYTHONPATH setting, so please use correct python codes only.

Comment: It's duplicated to this thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622041/python-importing-a-module-from-a-parallel-directory

Comment: I think this is different from that question because he's asking for pycharm and not command line.