# Module not found python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a hierarchy something like this:

```
 Assignment \
           -------__init__.py
           -------Presentation \
                  -------------__init__.py
                  -------------file1.py
           -------Business \
                  -------------__init__.py
                  -------------file2.py
```

i try to import the module in file 2 like: `from Presentation.file1 import Start_window`
Start window is a class
and same for file 2 but i got the error that: `No module named 'Presentation'`
I am a beginner in oo python so i have no idee why it doesn't work.

Comment: `from Assignment.Presentation.file1` perhaps? Since you've made `Assignment` the main package.

Comment: Modules are best / usually Imported under the interpreter of the whole project. Depending on what IDE your using, if pycharm , go to file, settings and import from there. Also you can import via Pip install module-name (in CMD or shell in your working environment). Don't forget to put in path (though 99% of time not be neccussary to do that for most python modules as python I suspect is in your path).

Comment: You should also mention from where you are running Python. Ideally, you run it from one directory above `Assignment`, and otherwise you set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to that directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python importing a module from a parallel directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622041/python-importing-a-module-from-a-parallel-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is not your folder-structure, but how you *start* Python.

Given your module structure, if you want to start `file2`, you should be *ABOVE* the `Assignment` folder and launch Python like this:
`python3 -m Assignment.Business.file2`.

This will make Python recognize `Assignment`,  `Business` and `file2` as modules, and let you import other things from them (both relative and absolute).

It is possible to add all these modules to the `PYTHONPATH` and use the normal way (without `-m`), but I found this to be way easier.