# Attempted relative import with no known parent package - cannot import python file from parallel dictionary

Tags: python

That's my project's structure

[image]

I'm trying to run stock_tracker_app.py, but I got the

> "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

There is problem within my second import.

```
import APIRequestFinnhub
from .. import stock_database
```

What should I do? I don't wanna waste time with messing up with my local database and moving everything into one dictionary. Please help me, at this point I really don't know how imports in python works. **It scares me.**

Comment: Do you work with python 2.7 or python3?

Comment: Hey :) Have a look at the answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622041/python-importing-a-module-from-a-parallel-directory

Comment: @DogukanAltay 3.9