# Python ImportError - packages

Tags: python, package

I'm fairly new to Python (mostly a Java / C developer) and am having a bit of import problems. I've read on many other posts here that to declare a package one must add `__init__.py` to the respective folder.

So here is what my structure looks like:

`app/
    src/
       __init__.py
       resumeParser.py
    tests/
       test_resumeParser.py`

So inside `test_resumeParser.py` I have the following line:

```
from src.resumeParser import *
```

and this is the line cauing me an ImportError: no module named 'src'

I'd appreciate any way to get around this issue. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3646370/471899

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/4714773

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `app` directory path to the [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) when run the test so that `src` can be imported:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/app python ....
```

Comment: Thank you - I don't know why I didn't think of that